# Visual Studio C++ 2019. How to convert wstring to WCHAR *

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, wchar-t

i tried google search a lot but only found the ways how to convert string to const LPCWSTR

I try this code but i can't success

```
string s = "ABCD";
wstring stemp = wstring(s.begin(), s.end());
WCHAR* sw = stemp.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar):

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    // Set /utf-8 or use u8 strings
    const std::string str = "\u7EDD\u4E0D\u4F1A\u653E\u5F03\u4F60";
    const int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), (int)str.size(), nullptr, 0);

    std::wstring wstr(size, '\0');
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), (int)str.size(), &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size());
    
    WCHAR* sw = &wstr[0];
}
```

Comment: thank you. if i read that string from file file. how to Set /utf-8 or use u8 strings ?

Comment: @ĐàmHồngĐức Just make sure the encoding is UTF-8. If you're reading from a file, use appropriate functions to read it as wchar_t instead of converting after the fact.

Comment: thank you. but how to read it as wchar_t ?

Comment: @ĐàmHồngĐức How are you reading it from a file now? Are you using the win32 API, or are you using iostreams/stdio?

Comment: i read that string from .txt file then i want to convert it to WCHAR* . I am doing a project related to win32 API . Sorry for not making it clear before

Comment: @ĐàmHồngĐức you can use `wifstream` to use iostreams. Or you can use `CreateFileW` and other win32 functions.

Comment: i tried 3 hours. I still can't do it. my txt file only reads 1 line as wchar_t* and other lines in a different format, is it possible?

Comment: @ĐàmHồngĐức can you share the file somehow so I can see for myself?

Comment: go to this link . I have my file and a detailed description

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jkTxiORuC0TfEZLD9hxu3RBUiSA8_IcB?usp=sharing

Comment: @ĐàmHồngĐức [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Ks1Pje3PE) works fine for me. What problem do you experience? The description file seems to be absent from the drive link you provided.

Comment: please try again . Sorry I uploaded missing files

Comment: @ĐàmHồngĐức as I pointed, you should be able to use `wifstream` to read the file as `wstring`. After that, to get a WCHAR*, use `&wstr[0]` where `wstr` is a `wstring`. The link I shared in the previous comment shows how to use `wifstream` to read line-by-line. It works fine with the file you uploaded.